# Why won't this Polymer's data binding work when the placeholder is not isolated?

Tags: polymer

```
<template>
  <p>this {{will}} not work</p>
</template>
```

while

```
<template>
  <p>this <span>{{will}}</span> work</p>
</template>
```

Is there any particular reason ? I got really confused until I found this till my code was actually running. And nothing in the doc was really (not) mentioning that.

Comment: [They actually did mentioned it](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#binding-to-text-content) and they marked it **bold**. Don't worry though, they are planning to have compound bounding and string interpolation soon as mentioned [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/#binding-features).

Comment: @NeilJohnRamal I was in the wrong place..thks